# System files are mounted readonly

Tags: boot, mount, cryptswap

My computer wont boot on Ubunutu anymore. I'm asked to enter my passphrase for encrypted disk (cryptswap1), but whatever I enter I get stuck on "Started Hold until boot process finishes up".

When I restart ad go into recovery mode as root, It seems like my disk is mounted on readonly, wich means an error has occured, but I cannot find the reason.

I've search a lot and done some modifications in my fstab ...

**EDIT**
In fact, at first my problem was the black screen. When my computer was booting, it would run into a command prompt, i could switch between virtual terminals but the cursor was always blinking and i my typing was completely messing. I then proceed to play with fstab and cryptoswap. And there I am.

Here is my fstab (manually pasted)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# / was on /dev/sda5/ during installation
UUID=3ad7f03b-61fb-437a-b283-bf10dcb1ab29 /    ext4    errors=remount-ro 0    1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=C0CB-1C88 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=6d24b49c-9ed6-4488-9824-a2d8e7547315 none swap sw 0 0
# /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
# UUID=C0CB-1C88 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
```

blkid

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL"ESP" UUID="C0CB-1C88" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="f715d64c-5122-4a85-80b6-ae46634bc810"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partion" PARTUUID="73367e4b-fe09-4fcf-aea7-2a90216ed20d"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="ACER" UUID="2e82d19982d1663d" TYPE="NTFS" PARTLABEL="basic data partition" PARTUUID="2c457b45-166f-4edb-81be-198fc75afab3"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="8adcd1dddcd1c41b" TYPE="NTFS" PARTLABEL="basic data partition" PARTUUID="13801b13-731a-4934-b9e6-0f1a6d1c7ab4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="3ad7f03b-61fb-437a-b283-bf10dcb1ab29" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2f1136fb-a3b5-4a88-9e56-936965529ec1"
/dev/sda6: UUID="6d24b49c-9ed6-4488-9824-a2d8e7547315" TYPE="SWAP" PARTUUID="bc5ca91f-cc95-4c60-9256-09598efdd131"
```

It's a dual boot with windows 7. I've separated /home and /.

Comment: IIRC filesystems are mounted ro in recovery mode by default - it doesn't necessarily indicate filesystem errors have occurred

Comment: I agree with @steeldriver.  It always mounts the drive as read only first in recovery mode.  If you need to perform changes you need to remount the drive as read write.  `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: I've mounted the drive as root with "mount -o remount, rw /" and resume the boot. Screen gets black with a blinking cursor. I can write, but nothing else, no command prompt.

Comment: Have you checked the drive for errors with `fsck`?  When booting to recovery mode it should be one of the options.

Comment: Hello, have you seen any progress with the situation? I have recently (today) had the EXACT same problem in the exact same system setup!

Comment: Fixed it by booting with a live usb, opening my encrypted drive in live Linux and deleting some files and freeing up space. If it matter, it said my community MySQL failed to start up which caused the hold until boot, which I think had to do with low space in my root.

Comment: I finally installed a new debian aside the first one. I will try to free some space from there